# issues using apache tika Parser object to parse .doc and .docx file formats

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika, file-type, .doc

When I try to use `org.apache.tika.parser.Parser` and `DefaultDetector()` to detect and parse the .doc and .docx file formats. But I am getting some error (not exception) thrown from Tika jars and that doesn't have any helpful stack trace for me to put here. I can confirm that it is happening for .doc and .docx only. PDF, jpeg, texts are fine. Has anyone come across this problem with .doc and .docx file formats? is there any solution that you have adopted?

My Code is the following:

```
unzippedBytes = loadUnzippedByteCode(attachment.getContents()); /* This is utility method written using native Java Zip library - returns byte array byte[] */

            /* All the objects below were declared beforehand, but not initialised until now */

            parseContextObj = new ParseContext();
            dObj = new DefaultDetector();
            detectedParser = new AutoDetectParser(dObj);
            context.set(Parser.class, parser);
            OutputStream outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            metadata = new Metadata();

            InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(unzippedBytes, metadata);
            ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(outputstream);
            detectedParser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseContextObj); // This is where it is throwing NoSuchMethodError - cannot understand why and also cannot get the stacktrace - using tika 1.10 */ 
            input.close();
```

The code above was something that I also found in some other SO question and decided to use it for my work. Also, the byte[] that I have used is something that I am receiving from very old struts 1.0 FormFile interface (getFileData() that returns byte[]). I used to have the bullhorn's irex parser to parse, but decided to use Tika for numerous reasons. the byte[] works fine with irex, but has issues whenever I am trying to parse .docx and .doc contents.

The following is the stack trace which I masked certain parts of due to privacy reasons:

```
2016-01-15 16:21:06,947 [http-apr-80-exec-3] [ERROR] XXXXX.XXXX.XXXXService - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[L
java/lang/Object;)V
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:313)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:163)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:131)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:561)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:109)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:80)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:125)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.<init>(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:245)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:227)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.ZipContainerDetector.detectOPCBased(ZipContainerDetector.java:208)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.ZipContainerDetector.detectZipFormat(ZipContainerDetector.java:145)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.ZipContainerDetector.detect(ZipContainerDetector.java:88)
        at org.apache.tika.detect.CompositeDetector.detect(CompositeDetector.java:77)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:112)
```

I realised that my path has POI jar version 2.5.1 and according to maven central repo I am a dinosaur (seems like) is that possibly why? I am also getting error after putting all [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231134/how-to-avoid-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-poi-util-ioutils-copyljava) for versions 3.13 and 2.60 for poi artifacts and xmlbeans respectively (suggested by @venkyreddy in that answer).

**UPDATE**
I tried building a new project separately from my original work, and used tika-app-1.10.jar ONLY in my classpath. I also investigated the `tika-app-1.10.jar` and found out that all the POI dependencies are actually there inluding `xmlbeans` and 'xml-schema'. After keeping only `tika-app-1.10.jar` in my classpath, I am getting the following Error (not Exception):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:158)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:167)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:119)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor.<init>(XWPFWordExtractor.java:59)
        at org.apache.poi.extractor.ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(ExtractorFactory.java:204)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:86)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:87)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxxxAttachmentWithTika(xxxService.java:792)
```

I browsed the package and couldn't find any POIXMLTypeLoader class. is this a known issue? Could someone please respond to me?

Comment: what version are you using? have you tried to change the logging level to THROW (see https://tika.apache.org/1.11/configuring.html "Load Error Handling") ?

Comment: What isn't working? What is the error?

Comment: @Gagravarr      when I used debugger watch, I see that the parser.parse method is throwing NoSuchMethod. As prescribed above, I will try and change the logging level to see if anything changes.

Comment: That implies that you've somehow stuffed up including Apache Tika and its dependencies into your application!

Comment: Is there any help on how to check the log configuration for Tika? In my project (inherited) I cannot see any xml file that has tika logs. Also, my tika jar is 1.10

Comment: Tika itself doesn't have any log configuration (if not speaking of tika-server nor tika-app). So, all logging is configured in you aplication. I recommend to  direct all logging via slf4j using some backend like log4j or logback.
You can find some info about deps at http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Logging.
After that, you'll have to configure chosen logging framework.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793939/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-p

Comment: @AxelRichter       Tried the solution proposed in your link, same result. All the path data seem to be correct as it is pointing out the jars I have added by following Tika and POI component lists. I also tried creating a separate MVN project and checking the resolved dependency list to double check if my list is correct, and it is. The only problem is I am using Ant and I __don't__ have the option to use Ivy (totally solves the issue I think).

Comment: Lazy option is to remove all the other dependencies, add the Tika App jar, and hope that the main class manifest doesn't clash... Or use the OSGi bundle

Comment: @Gagravarr                Please check my updated stack info. I confirmed that there isn't any class called POIXMLTypeLoader, so is this a bug or what?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any old versions of POI on your classpath. As [detailed in this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C), mixing POI jars between versions *is not* supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there are no outdated POI jars and use the version of POI which matches the version of Tika that you are trying to use.

The class `POIXMLTypeLoader` was added to POI after POI 3.13 was released, so it seems you somehow mix newer versions. Only release POI 3.14-beta1 knows about this class! Make sure you do not include that version somehow.